# What I want to know is What does my professor mean when she says...

Tags: calculus, integration

Find all anti-derivatives of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ using two variable as constant.

My First though was to take the integral of the function which is $-\frac{1}{x} + c$.
But what does she means by using two constant? Does she means to put $-\frac{1}{x} + c + a$.
Or that $g(x) = -\frac{1}{x} +c$ does representing the family of all anti-derivative of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$. But then  would that mean I need another function?  And thank you in advance, I don't want the answer to the problem I just want to understand what is asking.

Comment: Is that the exact problem statement? As such, it doesn't make much sense to me. Maybe you should email the professor and just ask?

Comment: @PSL Yes it is the exact statement...I did email my professor,nonetheless she didn't respond back. I would ask her in class, but the assignment is due tomorrow!

Comment: It's possible the prof means to compute $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ where the end points $a$ and $b$ are your two constants?

Comment: See [Can you have different integration constants for functions like $1/x^2$, one on each component of its domain?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566283/can-you-have-different-integration-constants-for-functions-like-1-x2-one-on?)

Comment: @JulioRosario Maybe there is a translation problem? Am I correct if I assume that the problem was not in English? If it was Spanish, I suggest you write a comment with the exact statement and someone could translate it.

Comment: @Greg.Paul Yeah most likely ... thanks for the help!

Comment: @MiguelAtencia What make you assume that? No it is not...

Comment: @JulioRosario Ooops... sorry